# Monitoring uwsgi with zabbix

Tags: uwsgi, zabbix

I would like to monitor uwsgi using zabbix. I found that there is some plugin for that:

```
uwsgi --stats-push zabbix:127.0.0.1:10051,myinstance ...
```

but I'm not sure how it is supposed to work. It seems that uwsgi pushes all the stats to the target zabbix but I can't find a description of this stats, hence I don't know how to set item(s) on zabbix.

For the moment I don't see anything coming to my zabbix instance.

Comment: What/where did you find that plugin?

Comment: Source is in uwsgi repo and there are packages around (for fedora at least)

Comment: Is you zabbix server listening on 127.0.0.1:10051 and you have the template imported from --zabbix-template as mentioned in the docu?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. run uwsgi with: --plugin zabbix  --zabbix-template and get actual
   template for uwsgi configuration.
2. import this template to zabbix and apply it to host with uWSGI server.
3. run uwsgi with: --stats-push zabbix:zabbix.host.name[,prefix to keys]