# how do I monitor uwsgi with zabbix？very confusing

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, zabbix

This problem has been bothering me for many days. I would like to monitor uwsgi using zabbix.I found that there is some plugin for that：

`uwsgi --stats-push zabbix:127.0.0.1:10051,myinstance ...`

link: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Metrics.html?highlight=zabbix

I don't know how to use it.

I attempt use `--zabbix-template` to get actual template for uwsgi configuration. But I don't get the right template. As shown in the figure below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB6NH.png)

Obviously, I didn't get a full template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452918/monitoring-uwsgi-with-zabbix

Comment: I see. But that answer doesn't resolve my problem.